# DJango: redirect form data, or pass form data to another view

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I have a form that needs to process some data in my django app, before the form data is passed to another app.

Is this possible? If not, how might I handle this situation?

Here's a more detailed example of what I need to do.  Any suggestions on HOW to accomplish this are welcome!

---

I have a comments app that tracks comments and replies on arbitrary objects, provides notifications, nested commenting, etc.  I'm trying to keep this app generic.

I have another app called "submissions" that uses the comments app.  A student enters a submission (via a CommentForm from the comments app) and the results are sent to the comments app which handles it.

In this case, I have two submit buttons on the form: Approve & Return

Regardless of which button is hit the comment app will handle the data the same.  However, my submissions app needs to do stuff based on which button was pressed.

The first way I thought of doing this was to pass the form to a submissions app view first, then redirect to the comments app, but I don't think the form data will come with it.

The second way was to only pass it to a submissions app view, then call a function in the comments app, e.g. Comments.objects.create_comment(...) instead of a view to handle the data, but I'm not sure how to pass the form data.

Answer (score 0):

This remembers me very much of this question: [django - how to implement a 2-step publish mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883826/django-how-to-implement-a-2-step-publish-mechanism)

You can use the session to save your data after you're done in step one (the submissions app, if I get you correctly), and then redirect the user to step two where they have to submit again (or just redirect again - that'd be a chain, so a bit of a minus there, but works).

Another possible way would be to hack/read a bit into the guts of the comments app to use its interna in the submissions app, so you combine both functionality into one view/function. But I can't help you with that without knowing the code (and it's your project after all, so it's your task).